# How to call the results of a query in a file that matches a loop structure in python

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I'm a beginner in python and i want to finish my school project.

My program consists of displaying the results of a query from my postgresql database and then making a function that formats the results of this query into a JSON file.

My code :

```
import psycopg2
import json
//Allows the connection to the database and displays the results in the terminal
def run(stmt):
    cur = psycopg2.connect(database='x', user='s', password='!', host='1').cursor()
    cur.execute(stmt)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    print(list(result))

//query that displays data from the database
stmt = 'select cast(row_to_json(row) as text) from (SELECT id, nom,  lon, lat FROM  u.b_l_b_s JOIN u.b_s ON b_s.id = b_s_id JOIN u.b_l ON b_l.id = b_l_id JOIN u.b_s_t ON   b_s_t.id = b_s_t_id ) row;'
    run(stmt)

//Output :
[('{"id":370,"nom":"MORO","lon":47.466001,"lat":-18.852607}',),     ('{"id":46,"nom":"NOROE","lon":47.473006,"lat":-18.852907}',),  ('{"id":45,"nom":"ANORO PLAQUE","lon":47.473404,"lat":-18.850003}',)
```

I want all the data of the query to be recorded in a loop (max 10) like this:

```
 {
   'stations': {
    result['label']: {
    'id': result['id'],
    'nom': result['nom'],
    'position': {
    'lat': result['lat'],
    'lon': result['lon']
                }
            }
    result['label']: {
    'id': result['id'],
    'nom': result['nom'],
    'position': {
    'lat': result['lat'],
    'lon': result['lon']
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance to those who will take the time to answer my question.

Comment: See [json](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#module-json) module, in particular `json.dump`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting close, but you may want to convert your values at the end.
There are functions in PostgreSQL to return a JSON array (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html), but I think they're more complex than what you need.

Instead you can use other features of Psycopg2. It returns tuples by default, but you can ask it to return dictionaries. This saves you from the manual conversion you're doing.

```py
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor

def run(stmt):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database='x', user='s', password='!', host='1')
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
    ...
```

Next, you are asked to return only 10 records. You could do this in your query by adding `LIMIT 10` at the end

`SELECT id, nom,  lon, lat FROM  u.b_l_b_s JOIN u.b_s ON b_s.id = b_s_id JOIN u.b_l ON b_l.id = b_l_id JOIN u.b_s_t ON   b_s_t.id = b_s_t_id LIMIT 10`

or you can do that when you fetch using fetchmany instead of fetchall. This is especially good if the table is large.

`result = cur.fetchmany(10)`

When you use RealDictCursor your results look a bit weird, its a list of 'RealDictRow' objects, but they still behave as a dictionary.

```py
>>> result
[RealDictRow([('id', 370), ...etc

>>> result[0]['id']
370
```

OK, so you have your ten records, and they are in a list dictionaries. Now you can loop over the list. Assuming you're returning a variable called `final_result` it could look like this:

```py
final_result = {'stations': []}  # we collect each result as an element of this list

for record in result:
    final_result['stations'].append(record) 

# finally, we convert it to JSON
json.dumps(final_result)
```